# Taking name of staff member who choosed status

Tags: php

I have something like this

```
|SUBJECT| |E-mail| |STATUS|
test1 cos@mail.com OPEN
test2 cos2@mail.com IN PROGRESS
test3 cos3@mail.com CLOSED
```

It's something like a ticket systems. When I want to open for example subject test1 I have all informations like Who, when, etc and also I have question from customer and I can reply and set status to: OPEN, IN PROGESS, CLOSED etc.

And it works fine but I wanna one addition.

I wanna something like:

```
|SUBJECT| |E-mail| |STATUS|
test1 cos@mail.com OPEN by Name Surname
test2 cos2@mail.com IN PROGRESS by Name Surname
test3 cos3@mail.com CLOSED by Name Surname
```

When I setting status I wanna take Name and Surname from my Staff and display it in my ticket view.

here is code: Choose status

```
<select class="select2" name="status">
<?php
foreach($statuses as $status) : ?>

<option value="<?php echo $status['status']; ?>">Set to <?php echo ucwords($status['status']); ?> </option> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

There is table like above:

```
<td><?php echo $ticket['subject'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $ticket['email'];?></td>
<td><?php echo ucfirst($ticket['status']);?></td>
```

I have bookmark Staff when I have all my "moderators"

```
$staff['name']
$staff['surname']
```

How Can I set who changed the status?

Comment: crazy idea, but have you considered adding a field to your table to store that information?

Comment: Maybe add a column containing the `id` of the staff member, rather than bits of useless text

Comment: Question is: where does that information come from? All you say is "take it from my Staff" which is pretty vague... What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have more robust and better ideas, but this will probably get to where you want to go:

```
<option value="<?php echo $status['status'].' by '.$staff['name'].' '.$staff['surname']; ?>">Set to <?php echo ucwords($status['status']); ?> </option>
```

Comment: The question is not "answerable" and this would not really work if the database stay's unchanged.

Comment: I interpreted his question such that he was pulling in the `$staff` variable from somewhere else. In that case I think my answer would work

Comment: Actually it works :D I just changed from 'name' and 'surname' to 'firstname' 'lastname'

Comment: glad to help :)